# Same docker image for different containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-image

I have one problem and maybe misunderstanding with docker images.

I need to run two separate mongodb 3.6 containers for my two different projects. But it seems that if use same image (mongo:3.6), then containers will use the same data, configurations, etc...

I use docker-compose to run and manage my containers. My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
services:
    first-mongo:
        image: mongo:3.6
        container_name: first-mongo
        mem_limit: 4g
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '27017:27017'
        volumes:
            - ${FIRST_MONGO_DB_LOCAL_PATH}:/data/db
            - ${FIRST_MONGO_DB_LOCAL_DUMP_PATH}:/data/dumps
            - ${FIRST_MONGO_DB_LOCAL_SCRIPTS_PATH}:/data/scripts

    second-mongo:
        image: mongo:3.6
        container_name: second-mongo
        mem_limit: 4g
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '27018:27018'
        volumes:
            - ${SECOND_MONGO_DB_LOCAL_PATH}:/data/db
            - ${SECOND_MONGO_DB_LOCAL_DUMP_PATH}:/data/dumps
            - ${SECOND_MONGO_DB_LOCAL_SCRIPTS_PATH}:/data/scripts
```

So, having this configuration my two containers run okay. However, when I took second container's ip address and tried to connect to database I saw the same data as in first container. Also, when I change something, the changes appear in both containers/images. Locally, I have different data in the first and second containers.

P.S When I change image tag for second container to, for example, mongo:3.5 I see database as I want to (separate data, etc).

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please check the host at the data directory it is mounted to

Comment: @YonahDissen how can I do this? I think I didn't understand you.

Comment: FIRST_MONGO_DB_LOCAL_PATH what's in this path?

Comment: @YonahDissen this is volume path to my local machine (to replicate the data). This directory has these folders: db, dumps, scripts. In db directory there are files with .wt format, mongod.lock, storage.bson, etc... The FIRST path and SECOND path has different amount of files.

Comment: Run docker inspect -f "{{ .Mounts }}" container_id

Comment: [{f4ef485dbbb28945d7191c04351e735ede57644be977f9403ed7c75214e6fa7d /var/lib/docker/volumes/f4ef485dbbb28945d7191c04351e735ede57644be977f9403ed7c75214e6fa7d/_data /data/configdb local rw true rprivate} { /home/tomas/Projects/first-project/.projectData/mongodb/db /data/db  rw true rprivate} { /home/tomas/Projects/first-project/.projectData/mongodb/dumps /data/dumps  rw true rprivate} { /home/tomas/Projects/first-project/.projectData/mongodb/scripts /data/scripts  rw true rprivate}]

The second container has different path: second-project/.projectData/...

Comment: Can you double check that across both of your running containers (check ports you are using in connection) you are having same data? Can you give us output of `docker ps -a`?

Comment: `CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                 NAMES
0580b53e9713        mongo:3.6           "docker-entrypoint.sh"   19 hours ago        Up About an hour    27017/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27018->27018/tcp   first-mongo
4a88f241664e        ceee4d1620d4        "docker-entrypoint.sh"   22 hours ago        Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp              second-mongo`

Btw, when I change image tag for second container to, for example, mongo:3.5 I see database as I want to (separate data, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to that problem. I just changed second-mongo container's ports configuration to:

```
ports:
    - '27018:27017'
```

Before it was 27018:**27018**. To be honest, I don't know how it was related, but it works for me now.

Thank you for people who tried to help me!